# cassandra data migration from regular drive to SSD on production server

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, data-migration, solid-state-drive

we want migrate our data from regular drives on production server to new SSD drives. how we can do that without taking down the node no longer than 4 hours(hinted hand-off is 4 hours) our data is in few hundreds of GigaBytes.

what i was thinking is stoping cassandra on one node at a time flushing data to disks and then transfering data from old drives to new drives and de-mounting old disk and bringing back node online. Is this a right approach ?? If so
what is my major concern is,the data migration to new disk takes more than 4 hours in the mean while i will lose hints.

Is there any better approach for migration of data to new disks??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the disk.

Use `rsync -avz --delete /old/data/dir /new/data/dir` to copy the sstables from one (spinning) drive to the other (ssd) drive. You can run this while cassandra is running - no risk other than increased latency due to IO contention. You can control the increase in latency using `nice` and `ionice`.

Once you've run rsync, you'll have an idea of the upper bound of the migration process. You'll also have an initial snapshot. Run it again, and time it a second time - it's likely going to be significantly faster - it'll leave files that haven't changed, delete files that have been deleted, and copy any new files. If this is faster than 4 hours (and it probably will be), then you can proceed to run `nodetool flush` and `nodetool drain`, stop cassandra, and run rsync a third time. Once rsync completes, change the path to the data file directory in the yaml, and start cassandra - hints will be delivered and you're good to go.

Alternatively, you can do the exact same thing, and if it takes longer than the 4 hour hint window, follow it with a `nodetool repair` to pick up any writes you missed when hints expired.